# Get Tax Rule Name in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I m getting `tax_calculation_rule_id` in `magento` so what i want is to get the `rule name` from `tax_calculation_rule` table. Is there any function that can help me doing this.

So basically this function will be a query to `tax_calculation_rule` table & will retrive code on basis of `tax_calculation_rule_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
$tax_calculation_rule_id = 10;

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$adapter = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = $adapter->select()
        ->from($resource->getTableName('tax/tax_calculation_rule'))
        ->where("tax_calculation_rule_id=?", $tax_calculation_rule_id);

$results = $adapter->fetchAll($query);

#checking output 
print_r($results);
```

p.s. [code] =>  is the name (you are looking)

Comment: Yes your answer worked for me ...... But i have one more question please help me on this too.
How can i get the `tax_calculation_rule_id` if i have product tax class and customer tax class. Currently i am working on a module in which i am trying to extend magento API's for tax rules. I have `customer tax class name` and `product class name`, Is there any function which can give me `tax_calculation_rule_id` on the basis of these two

Comment: Good to know. Can you please ask this question on separate post. That way it will be helpful to community

Comment: i have posted as different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749896/get-tax-calculation-rule-id-from-tax-class-in-magento