# Get tax_calculation_rule_id from Tax class in magento

Tags: php, magento

How can i get the `tax_calculation_rule_id` if i have product tax class and customer tax class. Currently i am working on a module in which i am trying to extend magento API's for tax rules. I have `customer tax class name` and `product class name`, Is there any function which can give me `tax_calculation_rule_id` on the basis of these two

Answer (score 4):

Try following:

```
$tax = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation');

//Get the rate based on customer class
$customer_tax_class = '5';
$rates = $tax->load($customer_tax_class, 'customer_tax_class_id');
print_r($rates->getData());

//Get the rate based on product class
$product_tax_class = '2';
$rates = $tax->load($product_tax_class, 'product_tax_class_id');
print_r($rates->getData());
```

Comment: In magento is there any possibility to apply 'customer tax class' and 'product tax class' at the same time. If yes, then at that scenario How would i get the 'tax_calculation_rule_id'.

Comment: Yes, it is sure possible. Since you are asking new type of topic, may be you create new question. In summery, you have to create request and get the tax rule i.e. $request = `Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest()->setProductClassId($productId)->setCustomerClassId($customerId);`

Comment: Thanks for the help Krishna, I have tried this code but it's not giving me the 'tax_calculation_rule_id'. Is there anything i am missing.

Comment: Make sure you have right value on `$product_tax_class = '2'` and `$customer_tax_class = '5'`. Otherwise it works 100%

Comment: Hi, I have tried this

$request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest()->setProductClassId('1')->setCustomerClassId('3');
var_dump($request);

Comment: To get the rate, you have to pass `$request` to getRate() function like `$percent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($request);`. `$percent` is the rate you looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57304/discussion-between-matya-and-krishna-sunuwar).

Comment: I have posted new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750890/tax-calculation-rule-on-basis-of-customer-tax-class-product-tax-class