# Tax calculation Rule on basis of customer tax class & product tax class

Tags: magento-1.7

How can i get the `tax_calculation_rule_id` if i have product tax class and customer tax class.

I tried this but it not giving me the `tax_calculation_rule_id`. Please help me with this.

```
$request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest()->setProductClassId('1')->setCustomerClassId('3');
$percent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRates($request);
```

On the above combination of `ProductClassId` & `CustomerClassId` my `tax_calculation_rule_id` is 2. How can i achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah... to get `tax_calculation_rule_id`, you have to use collection.

```
$taxCol = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation')->getResourceCollection();

$productTaxClassId = 2;
$customerTaxClassId = 5;

$taxCol->addFieldtoFilter('customer_tax_class_id', $customerTaxClassId)
       ->addFieldtoFilter('product_tax_class_id', $productTaxClassId);

print_r($taxCol->load()->getData());
```

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking on right sign if it worked for you. This way it remains useful to community